# NodeJS capturing large data from child processes without piping

Tags: node.js, pipe, console-application

In Node JS's child process documentation. The following is mentioned.

*By default, pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr are established between the parent Node.js process and the spawned child. These pipes have limited (and platform-specific) capacity.If the child process writes to stdout in excess of that limit without the output being captured, the child process will block waiting for the pipe buffer to accept more data.*

I've been trying to spawn (child_process.spawn) a console application from node. The application is interactive and outputs a lot of data on initiation. Apparently, when you pipe, if the process outputting data is getting a head of the process getting input, the OS pause the process outputting. For e.g, when you run `ps ax | cat`, if `ps` process is getting ahead of `cat` process, `ps` will pause until `cat` can accept input again. But it should eventually pipe all data.

In my case, this console application (written in C) seems to be pausing completely when this happens. I could be wrong but this seems to be the case because the piped output stops mid way no matter what I do. This happens even when I'm piping from bash, so there's no problem with nodejs here. May be this application is not very compatible with how piping works in linux.

There's nothing I can do regarding this console application but is there some other way in node to get these data chunks without piping?

**Edited:**

The main code

```js
const js = spawn('julius', ['-C', 'julius.jconf', '-dnnconf', 'dnn.jconf']);
```

I tried

```js
js.stdout.on("data", (data) => { console.log(`stdout: ${js.stdout}`); });
```

and

```js
js.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

to capture the output. Same result, the output is being cut off.

Comment: The key phrase in the documentation you quoted is "without the output being captured". The problem is that your code isn't capturing the output as it's supposed to be. Please post the code here so we can see why not.

Comment: Edit your code into your question. It's unreadable when you just put it in a comment.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: You're only handing `js.stdout`. See if doing the same for `js.stderr` too makes it work.

Comment: Tried it, the same result. This cut off happens even if I'm running the command directly from bash by piping. If I do `$  julius -C julius.jconf | less`, the output is still getting cut off. So the problem seems to be with this console application `julius`, not the nodejs code.

Comment: See whether `| cat` instead of `| less` also breaks it. If so, I'd say it's definitely worth asking the developers of julius about, since `| cat` is supposed to be a no-op (except in weird edge cases involving TTY detection).

Comment: Tried both cat and less actually, same thing. Seems I have to deal with julius somehow..
Thanks anyway.